# Getting the Android SDK directory within a gradle task

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Recently the gradle plugin for android got updated (with android studio), after which the previous way of getting to the SDK directory ceased to work. The expression

```
${android.plugin.sdkDirectory}
```

which worked in an older version now returns the error

```
Error:(42, 0) No such property: sdkDirectory for class: com.android.build.gradle.LibraryPlugin
```

What would be the proper way of getting the android SDK directory being used, preferably independent of the user's configuration such as plugin and gradle version? The script needs to be shareable with several users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since all the previous answers depend on the environment or specific user intervention on top of normal configuration, I'll just post my technically messy fix.

```
if (android.hasProperty('plugin')) {
    if (android.plugin.hasProperty('sdkHandler')) {
        androidPath = android.plugin.sdkHandler.sdkFolder
    } else {
        androidPath = android.plugin.sdkDirectory
    }
} else {
    androidPath = android.sdkDirectory
}
```

Unlike all previous methods, this actually works, but it still looks hacky.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work any more as of Android Gradle Plugin v. 1.1.3. Property android.plugin is now missing.

Comment: Any solutions for Gradle plugin version 1.1.3?

Comment: Use `android.sdkDirectory` (without `.plugin`) in that case. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

In `gradle.properties` set location `sdkdir=/home/user/android-sdk` and then in gradle you can use `$sdkdir`

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Android gradle plugin v1.2.3 and this works fine:

```
${android.sdkDirectory}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$System.env.ANDROID_HOME
```

Comment: As written yields a syntax error. Correcting the example to read `println "${System.env.ANDROID_HOME}";` returns `null` because the default behaviour for Android studio is to set the path via local.properties, and I was particularly looking for something configuration-independent.

Answer (score 0):

export ANDROID_HOME=/xxx/xxx/ in shell, then use it by System.env.ANDROID_HOME in gradle file.